# Dynamics CRM products for travel industry

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I work in the travel industry and am in the process of setting up dynamics crm for the business. Our products work in the following way. Each establishment has different accommodation types i.e. Budget room, family room, luxurious room. Each accommodation type has the following properties:

**Base rate number:** This is the number of people that the base rate applies to

**Base rate:** This is the rate for the base rate number.

**Extra Adult:** This is the cost per extra adult

**Extra Child:** This is the cost per extra child

So for example if the Base rate number was 2 and the base rate was $800 then the place would cost $800 regardless of if there was 1 or 2 people. Then any additional children or adults above 2 would be extra.

My initial thought was to create a new product for each accommodation type however I am not sure this is the correct route? Still trying to get my head around the product catalogue with regards to this.  My other worry is the system calculation of total cost on orders, can this be overridden using a plugin?

Any help, suggestions or reading is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've got so far.

I'd probably have the Establishment as the account entity ( purely company information )

Then potentially an Establishment entity, so if the company is say the Marriot an Establishment would be one of their hotels somewhere. So a company has multiple establishments.

At which point you would also have an accommodation type entity. Which would be against each establishment. As this may differ per establishment even if they belong to the same chain.

Then when someone is making an order and adding order products. There would be a lookup to an establishment and then a filtered lookup based on that for it's accommodation type.

They would fill out people numbers etc then a plugin would run on the order product entity which would calculate the cost for that instance, select the "override cost" radio button and then manually set the price per unit.

I can't say for sure as it sounds complex and obviously you have all the requirements so will know what's best. But i'd probably avoid the product catalog in this instance as it's mainly useful for individual products. Say you were selling Apples, you would have a Granny Smith Apple Product and then A Cox Apple product. These then get added to price lists which determine there mark up and sale quantity. When you create a quote / opportunity / order and select a pricelist it then uses these prices to perform the auto calculations. But it sounds that due to your custom calculations this may not be great behaviour hence the need for a plugin to calculate your costs and override for you.

That just my best guess =)

Comment: Thanks Chris, this seems like a solid point to start investigation from. From other research it does seem the product catalogue would not be robust enough for this scenario. For that reason i'm going to mark this as the answer. Thanks

Comment: When adding products to an order would I use a write in product?

Comment: If your just going to be using Orders, and not Quotes or Opportunities, Write in products are probably the best way to go.

Comment: If your using opportunities as well, It's probably best to look at creating your own product entity that is related to both opportunity and order as opportunity relies on a price list to tell it what products can be added to the opportunity.